# Displaying / Linking To A PDF

Tags: wordpress, pdf

i have just finished building a new website (wordpress), and i have a very strange problem linking to a PDF file.

I've uploaded a file to my website - http://goo.gl/tNxXYc - however when i enter the link in my browser it says that the page cannot be found, instead of showing the pdf.

Can anyone suggest what the problem might be? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

well, the  given google.gl shortcode forwards to https://www.grasshopperlanguagecentre.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/hello.pdf

and that file does not exist.

So find the correct location of hello.pdf and link to that.

Answer (score 0):

Please check permission of folder where pdf stored. Also try if any of following plug can solve your issue :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=pdf&sort=